# Given a set $A$ and $S$ is the successor function, prove that the class $\{S(x) : x \in A\}$ exists as a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

(This is from a problem set given years ago that I am self-studying.)

> > Let $S$ denote the successor function given by $S(x) = x \cup \{x\}$. Given a set $A$, prove that the class $\{S(x) : x \in A\}$ exists as a set, *without using replacement*.
> >
> > Hint: consider $\{y \in B : y = S(x) \text{ for some }x\in A\}$ for a sufficiently large set $B$

Does the hint not solve the problem by *Separation*, i.e., since $A$ is a set, there is a unique (by *Extension*) $B$ such that: $B=\{x\in A:\phi (x)\}=\{y \in B : y = S(x) \text{ for some }x\in A\}$.

If by chance this is correct, what constitutes a "sufficiently large" set $B$.

Thanks

Comment: What axioms are you allowed to use?

Comment: @AsafKaragila This set is based on Kunen - "Set Theory" (the latter edition), Sections I.5 - I.7. In checking, I.4 -I.5 have Extension, Comprehension, Pairing, Union, Infinity, Replacement, and Powerset. So looks like missing Foundation and Choice. Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: @AsafKaragila - Hi Asaf - Of course you are more than generous with your participation here. Maybe I could ask you if you have a sense why no one answered this question. (Not that I feel it's incumbent on you to answer it.) But maybe that itself would be instructive to me. Thanks. With regards,

Comment: Well, it's not a trivial exercise, and to be fair, I gave it some thought, but didn't have much time to really give it the attention it needs... I don't know about other people.